# How to resolve issue related to scala play application with sbt?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

With my current scala play application, I have tried to install Java and set their paths into environment variables.

To run application, I am using sbt. While hitting **Run** command of sbt with command prompt, I am getting following error message on command prompt.

```
    [CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:20):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfigXmlRead.init(InternalConfigXmlRead.java:42)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfigXmlRead.<init>(InternalConfigXmlRead.java:38)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:159)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:139)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:45)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:109)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:70)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1338)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
```

[image]

Is there something that is missing in environment setup ?

Comment: post the stack trace as text instead of image.

Comment: which jdk/jre version is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.0"
```

in your build.sbt